# SciKit Learn transformation pipeline output column number different for inputs of the same number of columns

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am currently learning ML and I am using scikit learn to preprocess two txt files (one for training and one for test).

After loading the data from the 2 files into 2 dataframes, and moving labels into two other dataframes (train_y and test_y) I am applying transformations to onehotencode labels and standardize numerical data.

```
train = pd.read_csv("./training.txt", delimiter="\t", header = None, names = col_names)
test = pd.read_csv("./test.txt", delimiter="\t", header = None, names = col_names)

train = train.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
test = test.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)

train_x = train.drop(["style"], axis=1)
test_x = test.drop(["style"], axis=1)

train_y = train["style"].to_frame()
test_y = test["style"].to_frame()

from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

num_attribs_X = ["calorific_value", "nitrogen", "turbidity", "alcohol", "sugars", "bitterness", "colour", "degree_of_fermentation"]

num_pipeline_X = Pipeline([('std_scaler', StandardScaler())])

full_pipeline_X = ColumnTransformer([
    ("num", num_pipeline_X, num_attribs_X),
    ("cat", OneHotEncoder(), ["beer_id"])
])

full_pipeline_Y = ColumnTransformer([
    ("cat", OneHotEncoder(), ["style"])
])

train_x_prepared = full_pipeline_X.fit_transform(train_x)
test_x_prepared = full_pipeline_X.fit_transform(test_x)

train_y_prepared = full_pipeline_Y.fit_transform(train_y)
test_y_prepared = full_pipeline_Y.fit_transform(test_y)
```

However, even though train_x and test_x have the same number of columns, train_x_prepared and test_x_prepared do not. I am unsure why is that the case? And is there a better way for doing what Ive done above?

Answer (score 0):

The problem should be at these lines:

```py
train_x_prepared = full_pipeline_X.fit_transform(train_x)
test_x_prepared = full_pipeline_X.fit_transform(test_x)
```

It should be:

```
train_x_prepared = full_pipeline_X.fit_transform(train_x)
test_x_prepared = full_pipeline_X.transform(test_x)
```

You use `fit_transform` on train set and use the fitted pipeline to `transform` the test set. If you use the `fit_transform` on test_set too, you might end up at different number of columns because the test set might lack some values in one column because of its limited size compared to the train set. Eventually when you apply `One Hot Encoder`, the smaller number of distinct values will show up in smaller number of columns.

Comment: what if both train and test dont have the full range of ids? How to pretrain an encoder on all possible labels then apply it later?

Comment: You can specify the list of categories (fill range of ids) using parameter `categories` in OneHotEncoder(). https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html